# Special character and icons didn't appear in my cmd while install vue-cli or laravel artisan command in windows

Tags: windows, laravel, vue.js, cmd

I had this problem in icons or special characters in cmd look like this

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try doing this: `composer require symfony/console:4.3.4` and check if it has changed, it's downgrading the symfony console, since there seems to be a bug with the latest once for Windows users

Comment: @Jesper thanks alot it is really a problem with this package it works fine the old version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bug with the latest version of `symfony/console`, so you you're facing this problem, then you have to downgrade with the following command:

`composer require symfony/console:4.3.4`

Note: It only seems to be a bug for Windows users at the moment.